# Why isn't Addressable working properly on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using the Addressable gem in my code and it works fine in development however it fails on Heroku:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def normalize_uri url
    uri = ::Addressable::URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
    (scheme = uri.scheme || 'http') + '://' + (host = uri.host || '') + uri.path
  end
end
```

On localhost this works fine however Heroku can't find the module.

```
app/models/user.rb:59:in `normalize_uri'
NameError (uninitialized constant Addressable)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Try `::Addressable` (note the `::`)

Comment: Make sure that `addressable` gem is in your `Gemfile`, and that you run locally with `bundle exec`...

Comment: @mdesantis good suggestion but I've still got the problem unfortunately - have updated to further clarify

Comment: What about `require "addressable"`? (after making sure that `addressable` is in the `Gemfile`, as @UriAgassi suggested)

Comment: ok, almost worked @mdesantis. I managed to find another project where I'd used it and `require 'addressable/uri'` did the trick. Can't remember why it needs the precision though...

Comment: yup heroku did not find `addressable` because it is not in Gemfile. @UriAgassi is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to include

```
require 'addressable/uri'
```

Bah.

Comment: And you didn't need it locally? It sounds weird o.O

Comment: @mdesantis. I know, I'm not really sure what was going on. I wonder if perhaps there was some way that I have a different set of gems installed locally and that one of those had pumped it into scope?